# @BeforeClass does not start the tests

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit4, selenium-firefoxdriver

@BeforeClass does not start my tests in Webdriver, Java, and I don't know where do I go wrong

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(baseUrl + "login");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("myUserName");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("myPassword"); 
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginBTN")).click();
}
```

After the code I start the regular testing:

```
@Test
public void firstTest() {
    //myTestCode
}
```

After attempting to run, all tests fail, the webdriver does not start, etc...

It would be nice to have this since I have to test a page where I have to be logged in (with @Before the webdriver starts before each test, so obviously I would need the @BeforeClass for this one.)

Comment: You can't start the driver before class because that's the object/instance never existed, first you need a class.

Comment: Two things:  I would only expect that `@BeforeClass` is invoked once, and that after it's run, JUnit will run the tests.  Also, could you provide what kind of failure you're getting?  Do you get an exception?  Are you using the same `driver` field in your tests that you're setting up?

Comment: What exception u are getting?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException is the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
```

//This needs to be here for this to run and having this here means its only local to this method
    Webdriver driver;

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(baseUrl + "login");
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("myUserName");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("myPassword"); 
driver.findElement(By.id("loginBTN")).click();
```

}

Then your Test will work

```
@Test

public void firstTest() {
//myTestCode
```

}

Comment: You made no modification to my code, except the comment you added which has no relevance to the answer. Please correct me, but did you forget the actual answer? :P

Comment: Hi the comment is relevance to your answer because its explaining that you creating the object driver will only exist before any class as such you'll always end up with a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code : Hopes this will work.

```
public class OpenBrowsers {

WebDriver driver = null;

@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() {
    System.out.println("beforeClass");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}

@Test
public void openGoogle() {
    System.out.println("openGoogle");
    driver.get("www.google.com");
}

@Test
public void openYahoo() {
    System.out.println("openYahoo");
    driver.get("www.yahoo.com");
}

@AfterClass
public void afterClass() {
    driver.close();
    System.out.println("afterClass");
}}
```

Comment: I have tried this, still same error: java.lang.NullPointerException is the error.